Problemas con Middleware
estoy en un proyecto usando nuxtjs2,en este momento me encuentro realizando un nuevo dash para un tipo de cliente en especifico, quiero protejer las rutas donde navegara este cliente por el cual le estoy especificando rutas del middleware depedendiendo si el cliente en si tendrá un true o un false en una variable global que guardo en el store,el problema es que a pesar que ya verifique que el usuario efectivamente tenga el b2b como true, aún así se dispara como si fuera false, por lo cual me quita el login, tendrá algun problema de actualizacion interna?
    ```
    <template>
      <div class="p-5">
        <h1 class="font-bold">Pedidos</h1>    
        <DashboardB2b />
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      layout: 'b2bDashboard',
      middleware: 'isB2b',
    }
    </script>
    ```
middleware 
export default async function ({ store, redirect, $toastr }) {

     if(store.state.auth.claims?.isB2b !== true) {    
        $toastr.error('Permisos no suficientes');
        await store.dispatch('auth/logout');
        return redirect('/auth/login');
     }
}


Aegurate que el estado isB2b se establezca correctamente en tu store.Puedes agregar logs temporales para verificar el valor del estado justo antes de la verificación en tu middleware
export default async function ({ store, redirect, $toastr }) {
    console.log("isB2b:", store.state.auth.claims?.isB2b); // Log para depurar
    if(store.state.auth.claims?.isB2b !== true) {    
        $toastr.error('Permisos no suficientes');
        await store.dispatch('auth/logout');
        return redirect('/auth/login');
    }
}

